# How to access my docker container (Notebook) over the Internet. My host is running on Google Cloud

Tags: apache, docker, tcp, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to access my container which is running a “dockerized” ipython notebook application. The host is a CentOS7 running in Google Cloud.

Here is the details of the environment:

Host: CentOS7/Apache Webserver running for example on IP address: 123.4.567.890 (Port 80 is Listening)

Docker container: An Jupyter Notebook application – the container is called for example APP-PN and can be accessed via the port: 8888 in docker.

It I run the application at my local server I can access the notebook application via the browser:
http://localhost:8888/files/dir1/app.html

However, when I run the application on the Google Cloud if I put:

http://123.4.567.890:8888/files/dir1/app.html
I cannot access it.

I tried all combinations open the port 8888 via TCP on the host as well as to expose the port via the docker run command – all of which did not work:

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8888/tcp --permanent

docker run -it -p 80:8888 APP-PN

docker run --expose 8888 -it -p 80:8888 APP-PN

Also I tried to change Apache to Listen to port 80 and 8888 but I got some errors.

However if I STOP the Apache Webserver and then run the command

docker run -it -p 80:8888 APP-PN

I can access the application simply in my browser via:
   htttp://123.4.567.890/files/dir1/app.html

HERE is my question:  I do not want to STOP my Apache Webserver and at the same time I want to access my docker container via the external port 8888.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see in your examples a 

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 APP-PN`

The `-p` argument describes first the host port to listen on and then the container port to route to. If you want the host to listen on the same port as the container, `-p 8888:8888` will get it done.

Comment: I tried 8888:8888 and it did not work. Especially when I opened the TCP port 8888 on my host. I just forgot to include it in my posting.